# telerik mvc grid access cell data to enable columns.Command

Tags: c#, grid, telerik, telerik-grid, telerik-mvc

I can't seem to find a way to reference the value in a column in the grid, in my case it is the StatusId.  Based on the cell value in this row, for the StatusId, I need to return a true or false to the method ".Visible(???)".  It would be nice to find the answer in the documentation online but I haven't been able to.  I find it hard to believe that I would be the first person who ever needed this functionality.

I would be most appreciative of any assistance since no one in the telerik forums know.

```
.Columns(columns => {
    columns.Command(commands => { 
    commands.Edit().ButtonType(ButtonType); 
    commands.Delete().ButtonType(ButtonType); 
}).Width(90).Visible(???);
```

Thanks!
AZee

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Visible` setting controls the visibility of the column. If set to `false` the column will not render at all. You can try using the `CellAction`:

```
.CellAction(cell =>
    {
        if (cell.Column.Title == "Commands")
        {
            if (cell.DataItem.StatusId > 0) //check whether to hide the cell
            {
                cell.HtmlAttributes["style"] = "visibility:hidden";
            }
        }

    })
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Korchev but that is not what I'm looking for... I'm seeking a way to not render the Edit and Delete buttons by using the Visible setting for their column.  My sample code works just replace the ??? with true or false.  What I need is a way to access a cell data on the current row and based on that data return a boolean value thereby not allowing the row to be edited or deleted.

Comment: As I said Visible affects all rows for that column. I think my code does exactly what you need. Use the DataItem property of the cell to determine whether to hide or show the column cell.

Comment: I tried but without any luck. In fact I removed the conditional just to see if could get the column to hideI even tried: .CellAction(cell => { if (cell.Column.Title == "Commands") { cell.HtmlAttributes["style"] = (new { style = "visibility:hidden;" }); } })

Comment: columns.Command(commands => {
   commands.Edit().ButtonType(ButtonType);
   commands.Delete().ButtonType(ButtonType);
  }).Width(90).Title("Commands");
 })
 .CellAction(cell => {
  if (cell.Column.Title == "Commands") {
   cell.HtmlAttributes["style"] = "visibility:hidden;";
  }
 })
and it still is visible!  I do appreciate your suggestion and time in trying to help!

Comment: I actually tried the exact same this before posting and it worked fine. Make sure you are using an up-to-date build.

Comment: I think your answer will help a lot of developers and the problem is probably somewhere else in my code. I did resolve the issue using OnRowDataBound
 .ClientEvents(events => events.OnRowDataBound(() => {%>
  function(e) {
   if (e.dataItem.StatusId != 1) {
    $(e.row).find('td.t-last a.t-grid-action').hide();
   }
  }
 <%}))
thx for all your assistance since it led me to a solution!

Comment: How to reference to Cell if cell.Column.Title is empty? I mean my column do not have title and there are several columns without titles.

Answer (score 0):

Above solution doesnt work with Ajax Binding ....For example if I want to show a perticular Cell's text Color in Red .." i.e. Cell_Text="In Error", when the Grid loads for the 1st time then this solution becomes applicable but when I apply some Ajax Actions on the said Grid like Filtering , then my Cell_Text again changes back to its normal text color .... Do you have any other codes for my perticular scenario